# Flutter - Draw a container with curve on one side around a circle (Not Radius Curve)

Tags: flutter, dart

How can i draw the below design in flutter ?

[image]

I was able to create a row of a rectangle and a small circle beside it but making the circle go ontop of the container and having the container being cut out is where the problem lies, i also tried stacking the two (rectangle and circle) and adding border of same background color to the circle but the result is not the same.

I am trying to achieve an end result that looks like this

[image]

Comment: like any other shape (`CircleBorder`, `StarBorder`, `RoundedRectangleBorder`  etc) you need a custom `ShapeBorder` class for that